# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: casting, gps, broadcastreceiver, classcastexception

This is my manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.devfret.mobile.Fretlink.receivers.GpsLocationReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

At the time I close the gps,  I get crash . with this line=> 
status.startResolutionForResult( (Activity)ctx , 1000);

my classes which I call this method (CheckAndOpenGps)extends AppCompatActivity .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.devfret.mobile.Fretlink.R;    

public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public GpsLocationReceiver() {
    }

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public Context contex;

    ContentResolver contentResolver;
    //    int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
//            contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
    //String locationMode="Gps is not activated";
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        this.contex = context;
        contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) contex.
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!IsGpsStatusActive(locationManager)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is not working. Please Activate the GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//emre changed

            CheckAndOpenGps(context, googleApiClient);
        } 
    }

    public static Boolean IsGpsStatusActive(LocationManager locationManager)//e
    {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    public static void buildAlertMessageNoGps(final Context ctx, final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) // emre yazdi
    {
        final LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mInflater.getContext());
        final AlertDialog.Builder builderexit = new AlertDialog.Builder(mInflater.getContext());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_off_turn_on).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            final int id) {
                CheckAndOpenGps(ctx, googleApiClient);   
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                builderexit.setMessage(R.string.canoot_work_without_gps).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    final int id) {
                        System.exit(0);    
                    }
                });
                final AlertDialog alertexit = builderexit.create();
                alertexit.show();
            }

        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show(); 
    }

    public static void CheckAndOpenGps(final Context ctx, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {

        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            //locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);//emre 30
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            //final GoogleApiClient finalGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    Log.d("statusCode", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()) + " message " + status.getStatusMessage());
                    //
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            break;

                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult( (Activity)ctx , 1000);

                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:** long story short you are trying to cast BroadcastReceiver's context to Activity here:

```
status.startResolutionForResult( (Activity)ctx , 1000);
```

Which is wrong, since those are two unrelated objects.

**A solution:** since the method does require Activity as a parameter, why not pass the activity there.
I suppose your app does have at least one Activity (if not, you can create one), so just pass the status to it in extras:

```
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, YourActivityName.class).putExtra("status-to-resolve", status));
```

And then in its `onCreate()` method you can unparcel your status and do the resolution:

```
Status status = (Status) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("status-to-resolve");

status.startResolutionForResult(this, 1000);
```